# "Kinds of measures" or "measures"

Tags: nouns

> 1. The **two kinds of measures** for preventing malaria are individual  preventing measures and community preventing measures.
> 2. Two **measures** for preventing malaria are individual preventing measures and community preventing measures.

I wanted to know whether  I should use use the word "kinds" or not in front of  "measures".

Comment: Unless you're intending to emphasize the fact that the two measures are of *completely different **types***, there's not really any point in including ***kinds of***. But that doesn't mean doing so is "incorrect" in contexts where you're not particularly interested in that fine point.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use "kinds" in front of "measures" because "kinds" signifies a category or group. There aren't only two measures, there are two GROUPS of measures.

While "kinds" is grammatically correct, and is often interchangeable with "types", using the word "types" instead sounds better: "The two *types* of measures for preventing malaria are..."

Comment: Those of you down voting, please let me know what issue you have with my answer.

Comment: I agree; it would be nicer to indicate what is wrong or suggest an improvement than just downvoting. It would bring a better benefit for the community. We are all *learners* here.

Comment: If I  use only 'measures',is it  correct?

Comment: No, because "individual preventing measures" and "community preventing measures" are not actual measures themselves, they represent sets of measures. If an individual were to ask you how could they prevent malaria, you would give them a list of measures the individual could take, not simply say "individual preventing measures".